# Google Geocoding API error: over query limit. - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I know this question has been asked but most answers were a few years old and not all for a Ruby on Rails project. In my current project, I am using the Geocode gem (via Ruby on Rails) and anyone is able to search users by their location (which I also use the Carmen gem for country, subregion).

Anyway, I've been receiving this issue lately (`Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.`). After reading up on it, I see that this is quite common. Most of the resolutions seem to involve caching but others say that it does not work much/well.

I wanted to pose the question to many here and see what various people think is a good resolution. Ideally it would be great to keep the Geocoding gem within the project, but if it is not worth it, please let me know of an alternative. If you know of a resolution to this issue, please let me know too.

Thank you and simply looking to receive feedback for this situation =)

PS: I do not use the Google Maps API. The project is setup so that a user enters their information (using Carmen gem) and typing the cit. The location is geocoded and others can type in a city, state/region to find users within that region.

**EDIT**

Additional Question: When this limit is met, would that also cause the longitude and latitude value to be nil when a user signs up? Since it is as the limit, it will not geocode the location entered and so it keeps the value at nil? I've had this happen before so I just want to make sure this is why =P

**EDIT 2 - ANSWER?**

After speaking a bit (in comments below), it seems the best option is to cache the information. With that being said, after researching I see that there are a lot of legalities when it comes to caching with google? Again I do not use the Google Map API so the legal aspect may not be relevant?

Would this be a good solution to implementing the cache (https://github.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/wiki/Customizing-the-geocoding-configuration)?

Just want to make sure I implement the cache aspect properly =P Thanks!

Joe

Comment: Have you taken the steps in the geocoder documentation?  For example only geocoding if the attribute you're geocoding by has changed on your models?  Is this in production?  If you're hitting it in development then it might be because everytime you're running a test it's making a request.  You could also look into the other geocoding providers it's compatible with i.e. bing, yahoo e.t.c

Comment: Are you using the free or work API? Keep in mind that the free API has a limit of 2500 requests per day as well as 5 requests per second.

Comment: Japed: This issue is happening in production. I have it setup that way, yes. It only gets geocoded if the location aspects have changed.
Kobaltz: Free API. I know that limit, which I am obviously hitting here. Just looking to see what options I have to not have this issue.

Comment: Then essentially I see your options as:
paying for it, using another provider with a higher limit, or caching

Comment: Japed: With caching, it would still have the same limit but the cache aspect would simply help allow a little more within that limit, correct? I have no idea on the price so I would have to research that.

Comment: You're still going to experience this problems initially, but the idea being if it's in the cache Geocoder will fetch the information from the cache rather than from google avoiding the request.  So if someone searches for London on your site then it'll hit google but then cache the result.  So the next person who searches for London it'll use the cache, avoid the request and it would almost certainly be faster too.

Comment: Japed: Oh! Well that sounds MUCH better! It may be tough at first, like you said, but as most searches are done, the more it will cache and it will be great. Wow, okay. I think this may be the best option for me =) I appreciate it! I'll read over the cache documentation on github. Can you look at y edit question and let me know if that makes sense? =P

Answer (score -2):

**ANSWER**

So after some research and help from japed (see comments above), I found this documentation (https://github.com/codeforamerica/ohana-api/wiki/Customizing-the-geocoding-configuration) which clearly explained how to setup Redis with Geocoding for caching purposes. It also provided another link with more information to test it in development before deploy.

Thank you!

Joe