# Rails geocoder - Google Geocoding API error: over query limit - PRODUCTION ONLY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

`geocoder` gem has stopped working solely in the production environment. It works perfect and as expected in development.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 using ruby 2.3.1 and rails 4.2.6

When I run ModelName.near("zip_code", "radius") in development from the `rails console`, I am returned the associated rows as expected. When I run the same command in the server, it returns `Google Geocoding API error: over query limit.`

**UPDATE**

`lat` and `long` are not being saved in the production environment, but are being saved in development.

Comment: You have two options: 1. Sign up for pay-as-you-go with Google so you don't hit rate limits (see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits)) 2. Cache lookups or otherwise optimize your app to hit the API less (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31618535/2981429))

Comment: I definitely have not hit anywhere near the 2500 cap to need to upgrade to need to enable pay-as-you-go account. I am wondering why I am able to get the query to work in development, but failing in production with the `over query limit` error? Thanks for the references btw.

Comment: I also put a `sleep(2)` to see if that would fix the problem, but still did not.

Comment: did you manage to figure out the reason for this query limit? i'm experiencing a similar issue...

Comment: No, this is still an open issue as I too am still experiencing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Adding my google api key to config/initializers/geocoder.rb resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I will give it a try when I work on that project this week! I will update with my results as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a key for GeoCoder resolves this issue:

Create a file **config/initializers/geocoder.rb** and paste below code:

```
Geocoder.configure(
  api_key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
)
```

You need to replace "YOUR_API_KEY" with a valid Google Geocoder API key.

Status codes are available at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#StatusCodes